# A more perfect Union[]

Tags: performance-tuning, sets

I was doing a *Project Euler* problem with my class, and found the following weird fact: `Union[]` of a list of some 50 million numbers (of which only around 15000 were distinct) took about 30 seconds. `DeleteDuplicates[]` of the same list took well under one second.

Since the functionality of the two is identical, except for one returning the results in sorted order, I am at a loss to explain this (sorting 50 million records should take much, much less than a second, leaving aside the fact that I would implement `DeleteDuplicates[]` by a sort). Why *is* `Union[]` so slow?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17535/discussion-on-question-by-igor-rivin-a-more-perfect-union).

Comment: @Igor I like the discussion about the difference between Union and DeleteDuplicats and I have read the chat-log. However, I'm still puzzled by the title of your question. What do you expect from a possible answer? Daniel showed how to implement a sorting algorithm low-level, but is this really what you wanted? I guess it will be hard to come even close to the speed of the built-in `Sort` and why is `Sort[DeleteDuplicates[list]]` not a solution? Could you maybe insert a question mark anywhere in your, well, *Question*?

Comment: @halirutan Fair point. The question is really "why is `Union[]` so slow?", and this is more-or-less answered in the answers. I will edit.

Comment: See also [this closely related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64040/4330), especially because there is no accepted answer here.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the speed of Mathematica's `Sort` is reasonably in line with other languages. For example, on my laptop a 30,000,000 real list took 30 seconds to sort in Mathematica; the same computation in Julia (which is designed for high-performance scientific computing) took 10 seconds. So it's well within an order of magnitude speed compared to other implementations.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I am not satisfied with the so called "well within an order of magnitude". Now that built-in function is implemented in C in mma, why `Sort` should be slow? Not to mention Julia, Let us compare mma with Python's numpy package, numpy is also written in C. But sorting a 10 million reals takes 6.3 sec with mma, while only 2.3 sec with numpy. Although `Sort` in mma is more general of being able to sort symbols. But this is not the reason that `Sort` should be slow, because we already feed `Sort` packed array, there should not be any performance lag

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I'll go first. This is not an answer per se to the post, but more an invitation to write a fast sorting code for machine reals. That way we can get some sense of what might be feasible (showing timings of existing implementations would also be useful; I leave that for others). In Mathematica. Using `Compile`, of course. The point is to illustrate a few things.

(1) It's not easy.
(2) My code might be somewhat on the lame side.
(3) Data locality is extremely important.
(4) The `Compile` usage of a C compiler might be less optimized than one would like.

I'll do implementations of heapsort and mergesort. For the latter I have both a recursive and nonrecursive variant. We'll see that heapsort, at least my take on it, is hopelessly slow. I suspect that has as much to do with data nonlocality as with my own coding of the algorithm. The "R" in these stands for "reals". Also for reasons I no longer recall, I started by implementing sorts from large to small, then switched at the end to the "usual" sort. So some of these need reversing before comparing to built-in `Sort`.

```
heapSortR = Compile[{{ll, _Real, 1}}, Module[
    {n = Length[ll], heap, j2, jj, res},
    heap = ConstantArray[0., n];
    Do[
     heap[[j]] = ll[[j]];
     {jj, j2} = {j, Floor[j/2]};
     While[j2 >= 1 && heap[[j2]] < heap[[jj]],
      heap[[{j2, jj}]] = heap[[{jj, j2}]]; jj = j2; j2 = Floor[j2/2];
      ];
     , {j, n}];
    res = ConstantArray[0., n];
    Do[
     res[[j]] = heap[[1]];
     heap[[1]] = heap[[n - j + 1]];
     jj = 1;
     j2 = 2;
     While[j2 <= n - j + 1,
      If[j2 <= n - j && heap[[j2]] < heap[[j2 + 1]], j2++];
      If[heap[[j2]] < heap[[jj]], Break[]];
      heap[[{j2, jj}]] = heap[[{jj, j2}]];
      jj = j2;
      j2 = 2*jj;
      ];
     , {j, n}];
    res
    ], CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

 mergeSortR = Compile[{{ll, _Real, 1}}, Module[
    {n = Length[ll], n2l, n2r, left = {0.}, right = {0.}, jl = 1, 
     jr = 1},
    n2l = Floor[n/2];
    If[n <= 2, Return[Reverse[Sort[ll]]]];
    left = mergeSortR[Take[ll, n2l]];
    right = mergeSortR[Drop[ll, n2l]];
    n2r = Length[right];
    Table[
     If[jl <= n2l && jr <= n2r,
      If[left[[jl]] > right[[jr]],
       jl++; left[[jl - 1]]
       ,
       jr++; right[[jr - 1]]]
      ,
      If[jr > n2r,
       jl++; left[[jl - 1]]
       ,
       jr++; right[[jr - 1]]]
      ], {n}]
    ], CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

--- edit remark ---

The version below is a (very) small improvement over the one I had originally posted.
It is still around 5-6 times slower than built-in `Sort`.

--- end remark ---

```
mergeSortRnonrecursive = Compile[{{ll, _Real, 1}}, Module[
    {n = Length[ll], m = 1, n2, jmid, jl, jr, jlnew, jrnew, lr, j1, 
     j2, j, merged, stack, work, work2},
    n2 = Floor[n/2];
    If[n <= 2, Return[Reverse[Sort[ll]]]];
    work = ConstantArray[0., n];
    work2 = ConstantArray[0., n];
    stack = ConstantArray[0, {Ceiling[n/2], 3}];
    stack[[{m, m + 1, m + 2}]] = {{-1, 1, n}, {-1, 1, n2}, {1, n2 + 1,
        n}};
    m += 3;
    While[m > 1,
     {lr, jl, jr} = stack[[m - 1]];
     If[jr - jl <= 2,
      work[[Range[jl, jr]]] = Sort[ll[[jl ;; jr]]];
      m--;
      While[lr == -1 && m > 1,(*merge with partner on right*)
       m--;
       {lr, jlnew, jrnew} = stack[[m]];
       j1 = jl;
       j2 = jr + 1;
       Do[
        If[j1 <= jr && j2 <= jrnew,
          If[work[[j1]] < work[[j2]],
           j1++; work2[[j]] = work[[j1 - 1]]
           ,
           j2++; work2[[j]] = work[[j2 - 1]]]
          ,
          If[j2 > jrnew,
           j1++; work2[[j]] = work[[j1 - 1]]
           ,
           j2++; work2[[j]] = work[[j2 - 1]]]
          ];
        , {j, jl, jrnew}];
       work[[Range[jl, jrnew]]] = work2[[jl ;; jrnew]];
       jr = jrnew;
       ];
      Continue[];
      ];
     jmid = Floor[(jr + jl)/2];
     stack[[{m, m + 1}]] = {{-1, jl, jmid}, {1, jmid + 1, jr}};
     m += 2;
     ];
    work
    ], CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Here is a basic test.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
rvals = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10^6];
Timing[svalsH = heapSortR[rvals];]
Timing[svalsM = mergeSortR[rvals];]
Timing[svalsMnr = mergeSortRnonrecursive[rvals];]
svalsH === svalsM === Reverse[svalsMnr] === Reverse[Sort[rvals]]

(*
{6.804000, Null}

{5.136000, Null}

{1.228000, Null}

True
*)
```

It should be clear that none of these is competitive in speed with the built-in Sort. Yet they do use C code under the hood. So while I do not question the possibility that `Sort` is needlessly slow, I will point out that it might take serious effort to make one considerably faster.

--- edit ---

One other thing to note is that there are dependencies on a "lowest level" sorter, one that gets used below a given threshold. In the code above I use built in `Sort` on lists of length 3 or less. If we up that threshold to 16 then the speed improves by a factor of 2.5 or so. But now we use `Sort` on substantially larger lists, and that, arguably, is cheating. To make it fair I'd need to write a pedestrian (perhaps O(n^2)) sorting code that works fast for small lists. Offhand I do not know if that would be in the realm of possibility (and do not have time or patience to find out).

--- end edit ---