# Why some built-in functions are slow

Tags: performance-tuning, core-language, language-design, function-comparison

I just wonder why some built-in functions are slower compared to some other ways using more than one built-in functions for doing same job.

consider this example:

```
list = RandomInteger[10000, 10000000];

Timing[sol1 = Union[list];]

(*{2.265625, Null}*)

Timing[sol2 = Sort[First /@ Tally[list]];]

(*{0.031250, Null}*)

sol1 == sol2

(* True*)
```

One  built-in function (`Union`) is so slow compared to four  built-in functions (`Tally`, `Map`, `First`, and `Sort`) .

**Questions:**

1- why is that happening?

2- how to know that there is faster way (using more than one built-in function) for doing job compare to one built-in function? is it just by experience?

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates` should be even faster! [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61011/4330) is strongly related. The answer is pretty much given in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17535/discussion-on-question-by-igor-rivin-a-more-perfect-union) that was created to discuss this.

Comment: As for the more general question why built-ins are slower than what users can cobble together I think that is answered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54865/731) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55332/731). TL;DR There is no good reason. Developers just haven't gotten around to optimizing those functions yet.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**The general case**

There are indeed some functions in *Mathematica* that are/were not performing nicely. The one I am most scared of is `Total` ([the issue is addressed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63209/4330)) (update: apparently `Total` has been fixed in version 10.0.2). User [C.E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) provides some more examples in his comment. But I feel the case of `Union` is different, as it is simply specialised for a specific case and in this case it performs well.

**The case of Union**

The way I see it, there is a spectrum of lists on which `Union` has to work. On one side of the spectrum, there are many duplicates, on the other few. `Union` is optimised to handle relatively few duplicates, and here it is unbeatable. But for many duplicates, using `DeleteDuplicates` first is faster.

To see that this is true, one can experiment with the following code.

```
mm = 1*^6;
kk = 1*^4;
rands = RandomInteger[kk, mm];

(res1 = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[rands]]) // Timing // First
(res2 = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[rands]]) // Timing // First
(res3 = Union[rands]) // Timing // First

res1 == res2 == res3
res1 == Range[0, Min[kk, 10^6]]
```

> ```
> 0.003440
> 0.152277
> 0.149979
> True
> True
> ```

Here there are many duplicates, so that `Sort@*DeleteDuplicates` is faster. Compare this with

```
kk = 1*^10;
rands = RandomInteger[kk, mm];
(res1 = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[rands]]) // Timing // First
(res2 = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[rands]]) // Timing // First
(res3 = Union[rands]) // Timing // First

res1 == res2 == res3
res1 == Range[0, Min[kk, 10^6]]
```

> ```
> 0.376823
> 0.365987
> 0.175067
> True
> False
> ```

where there are few duplicates, and `Union` is unbeatable.

At first I felt that it was strange that `Union` was so focussed on the few-duplicates case, but then again, techniques like sampling the list to see how many duplicates there are are pretty ugly and heuristic at best. I think the choice to make `Union` work like this is all right, though I think it should be documented more clearly.

In the documentation of `DeleteDuplicates` one can find that deleting duplicates can be much faster than "using `Union`". However it does not say that in cases like this it may be better to use technique of deleting duplicates first and then sorting.

A tricky part of understanding all this is understanding that `DeleteDuplicates` can be so much faster. I think the power of the hash table is easily underestimated, and to think that it is always a good idea to delete duplicates by sorting elements is an easy mistake to make.

I would love to see something like an option of `Union` to make it assume it is dealing with many duplicates. It must be possible to make something that is (at least a little bit) faster than using `Sort@*DeleteDuplicates`. That would also mean that the issue would have to be addressed in the documentation of `Union`.

Comment: +1, but I think this should compare with the same length list having many and few duplicates as well as duplicated items. Without having tested it, I think you might be seeing trade-offs between the $O(n^2 \log{n})$ average case behavior of `Union` (worst case for pathological lists: $O(n^3)$), the $O(n)$ average case for `DeleteDuplicates`, and the $O(n^2)$ worst case for the same, which will happen if there are many different duplicated items. (I am guessing about the complexity of `Union`. It could be just $O(n \log{n})$ average case and $O(n^2)$ worst case, as for quicksort.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. thank you for your comment. I am not entirely sure what you mean with your first sentence. The lists here have the same size, which is `mm`. I suppose it could be nice to add the observation that `Union` does not get much slower, whereas `DeleteDuplicates` does, when have fewer duplicates. I think a comparison in terms of big O notation is also useful. I think delete duplicates indeed takes $O(n)$ time. For fixed `kk` a $O(n\, log(n))$ algorithm for `Union` exists, as an algorithm would be to first delete duplicates and then sort, an with abuse $O(n)+O(n\,log(n)) = O(n\,log(n)) $

Comment: I do not know about the actual implementation of `Union` of course. [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17927901#17927901) Leonid says `DeleteDuplicates` can be $O(n)$ and that `Union` can use a $O(n\,log(n))$ algorithm. All my statements so far have been about worst case, though I like your distinction between the average and worst case. If we let `kk` depend on $n$ in such comparisons and then `Union` may (I think) have better asymptotic behaviour than `DeleteDuplicates`. If you feel the answer can be made better feel free to edit it, I cannot do so right now.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. I was typing faster than I was thinking when I wrote that, and surely `Union` must be $O(n \log{n})$ average case, not $O(n^2 \log{n})$, as it's not necessary to scan the entire list to remove each duplicate if it's already sorted. (Note that Quicksort is $O(n^2)$ worst case, though this is seldom seen in practice.) The cost of looking an item up in a hash table is $O(1)$, but it's $O(m)$ to (re)build it ($m$ entries), so $O(mn)$ or roughly $O(n^2)$ if it needs to be rebuilt $O(n)$ times, as if there are many widely dispersed but seldom duplicated items in the input.

Comment: In summary, I think we probably have $O(n^2)$ worst case for both `Union` and `DeleteDuplicates`, except that the worst case for the latter is more frequently observed and probably has a larger constant factor. The average case will be $O(n \log{n})$ and $O(n)$, respectively, as you say.