# Fast way to retrieve list of vertex and edge properties

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

*[Cross posted on W Community.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1072008)*

---

I am looking for a fast way to retrieve the vertex and edge property names present in a graph, [for use in IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/Utilities.m#L317).  There should be two functions:

```
vertexPropertyList
edgePropertyList
```

which will each return a list of property names. They should work on *any* graph.  They should return properties which are present on only some of the vertices or edges.

Naïve and slow implementations:

```
vertexPropertyList[g_?GraphQ] := 
 Union @@ (PropertyList[{g, #}] & /@ VertexList[g])
edgePropertyList[g_?GraphQ] := 
 Union @@ (PropertyList[{g, #}] & /@ EdgeList[g])

g1 = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", 
    "CondensedMatterCollaborations2005"}];

g2 = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "HighEnergyTheoryCollaborations"}];

g3 = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[50000, 0.005]];

{AbsoluteTiming@vertexPropertyList[#], AbsoluteTiming@edgePropertyList[#]} & /@ {g1, g2, g3} // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Bounty update

**Current best solution, based partly on @kglr's answer below:**

This is the one to beat for the bounty:

```
hasCustomProp[g_] := OptionValue[Options[g, Properties], Properties] =!= {}

standardVertexProperties = {
  VertexCoordinates,
  VertexShape, VertexShapeFunction, VertexSize, VertexStyle,
  VertexLabels, VertexLabelStyle,
  VertexWeight, VertexCapacity
};

ClearAll[vertexPropertyList]
vertexPropertyList[g_ /; VertexCount[g] == 0] = {};
vertexPropertyList[g_ /; GraphQ[g] && hasCustomProp[g]] := Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ PropertyList[{g, VertexList[g]}]]
vertexPropertyList[g_ /; GraphQ[g]] := Intersection[PropertyList[g], standardVertexProperties]
```

---

**Things I already tried:**

To save people time, here I will show approaches that I tried and that did not prove fruitful.

We can get the custom properties and their values like this:

```
Options[g, Properties]
```

We could try to extract the property names from this structure.  The problem is that edge and vertex properties must be separated.  So we start with filtering vertices:

```
vertexProps = Lookup[
   Association@OptionValue[Options[g1, Properties], Properties],
   VertexList[g1]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.160342, Null} *)
```

This in itself takes longer than

```
PropertyList[{g1, VertexList[g1]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.093381, Null} *)
```

So at least this implementation is not going to be fast enough.  It does not mean that there isn't another way to use `Options[g, Properties]`.

Comment: Make a [note](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64043/21532) here.

Comment: Do you think ``GraphComputation`GraphAbsoluteOptions[
 ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "EastAfricaEmbassyAttacks"}]]`` can help?

Comment: you could also define hasCustomProp for edge and vertex separately. For example, hasVCustomProp[g_] := 
 MemberQ[OptionValue[Options[g, Properties], Properties][[All, 1]], 
  x_ /; VertexQ[g, x]]
hasECustomProp[g_] := 
 MemberQ[OptionValue[Options[g, Properties], Properties][[All, 
    1]], _DirectedEdge | _UndirectedEdge]

Answer (score 5):

Also naive but faster:

```
ClearAll[vertexPList, edgePList]
vertexPList[g_?GraphQ] := DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ PropertyList[{g, VertexList[g]}]]
edgePList[g_?GraphQ] := DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ PropertyList[{g, EdgeList[g]}]]

{AbsoluteTiming@vertexPList[#], 
    AbsoluteTiming@edgePList[#]} & /@ {g1, g2, g3} // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

versus

```
{AbsoluteTiming@vertexPropertyList[#], 
    AbsoluteTiming@edgePropertyList[#]} & /@ {g1, g2, g3} // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great!  Small but useful improvement from DeleteDuplicates.  Please also see the comments I just posted on W Community.

Comment: You can make a further slight improvement by putting another `DeleteDuplicates` before the join. (This mostly helps if there are many edges/vertices with the same set of properties.)